# Github pagination how it works

Tags: github, github-api-v3

I want to get the list of all repositories in GitHub with pagination and I want to set items per page to for example 50.
for that, I use this

```
https://api.github.com/repositories?page=1&per_page=50
```

but it doesn't work and always I get 369 items per page

what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The [GitHub API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) give this answer:

Note: Pagination is powered exclusively by the since parameter. Use the Link header to get the URL for the next page of repositories.

For pagination your url could like like:
https://api.github.com/repositories?since=19991704